# My entity is not added via the async method

Tags: .net, asynchronous, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add data to my model async.

I have the model below.

```
public class Versions
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TechnologyId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Version")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BindNever]
    public int Ordinal { get; set; }
}
```

I add it in Repo with a method  below

```
public async Task Add(Versions entity)
{
   entity.Ordinal = GenerateOrdinal(entity.Name);
   await context.Versions.AddAsync(entity);
   await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I'm pushing the new version list in a loop to my repo

```
foreach (var item in NewVersions)
{
      Versions version = new Versions();
      version.TechnologyId = technology.Id;
      version.Name = item;
      await versionsRepository.Add(version);
}
```

I am not getting any errors. But no version on my list is added. What is the reason for this?

Note: GenerateOrdinal() method works synchronously. And it returns a serial number by param string structure.

Comment: Your version entities are not added in the database, am I correct?

Comment: Nope. It has already been added.

Comment: `But no version on my list is added.` - What does it mean?

Comment: I have a string list called NewVersions. The data in it hasn't been added.